# Firebug not displaying all object properties

Tags: javascript, debugging, console, firebug

I'm tracking some data using console.log, an object with form data, and because the amount of data is greater than what FB will display in the console I get a "more..." appended to the string displayed in the console:

```
 Object { elementName="lessonPlanName", elementType="text", more...}
```

But when I click on the link I get message saying "There are no properties to show for this object."

How can I view all the items of the object in the console?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a Firebug bug—happens sometimes. Try closing the tab and reopening it, it sometimes works, but usually you have to close Firefox completely.

Additionally you can do a lot more than just console.log. `console.dir(obj)` and `console.dirxml(ob)` for example. One is made for outputting object key/value pairs and one is made for outputting xml.

See the full docs here: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API

Answer (score 10):

'Show User-defined Properties' under DOM tab must be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

disable **Show Own Property Only** in DOM panel